# Skipping If statement

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questionaire {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name;
    String ansOne;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Hello, welcome to the super awesome quiz. Let's get things going. What is your name?");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Okay, hi " + name + " I'm just going to call you Bob.");
    System.out.print(" Question 1: What is the name of your dog?");
    ansOne = input.nextLine();

    if (ansOne == "Avagantamos") {
      System.out.print("Correct!");
    } else {
      System.out.print("Wrong! The correct answer was Avagantamos!");
    }

  }
}
```

So basically, when it asks you to type in the name of your dog, it's always incorrect, even when you type Avagantamos. I'm still really noob and this has been really frustrating so thank you so much to whoever responds.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  +1 for providing all the necessary details for someone to answer your question (you'd be surprised how often that's not the case).  When entering code, please try to format it correctly, and indent the entire block 4 spaces so SO will display it using a fixed-width font.  There's a button `{}` on the input page that will indent everything that's selected 4 spaces.  Andrew did this for you.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `==` to compare Strings. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method.

Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if (fu.equals("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if (fu.equalsIgnoreCase("bar")) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. The responses on this forum are lightning fast.

Comment: @JakubZieba: You're welcome. We see this question a lot, so don't be surprised if it gets closed and deleted for this very reason.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.compareTo()` (or `String.equals())` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2):

When comparing strings, use `.equals()`, not `==`. This is because `==` compares objects according to reference identity, and there may be multiple `String` instances that contain the same data. The `.equals()` method will compare the contents of the `String`s, which is what you want. So you should write

```
 if (ansOne.equals("Avagantamos")) {
```

In this case, it seems that `input.nextLine()` is constructing a new `String` object, which is why `==` doesn't work.

Incidentally, you probably wanted to use `System.out.println` rather than `.print`; otherwise the prompts and output will all be run together on one line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ansOne.equals("Avagantamos")`

`==` compares the references of the objects.